# the number of $~(x,y)~$ such that $~x^{2}-y^{2}\equiv 1 \pmod {2000})$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

everyone.

The following is the problem and the part of my answer.

Find the number of $~(x,y)~$ such that $~x^{2}-y^{2}\equiv 1 \pmod {2000}$ where $~0\leq x,y \leq 1999$

I found out that $~x\equiv 1 , -1 \pmod 8~$ and $~y\equiv 0, 4 \pmod 8~$ but can't go any more.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show/check your work? There are 8 solutions mod 8. In particular, we could have any combination of $ x \equiv 1, 3, 5, 7$ and $y \equiv 0, 4$.

Comment: you are right. 1,3,5,7 are correct. I saw the answer right now and it's 1600. Can you explain yours more?

Comment: I am reasonably confident of my solution. If there is something you do not understand, please ask about it specifically. I do not know what "explain more" you need. EG Do you know what CRT is? Do you know how to solve mod 8? etc.

Answer (score 2):

- By CRT, we only need to consider mod 16 and mod 125.
- Taking mod 16, since $ n^2 \equiv 0, 1, 4, 9 \pmod{16}$, it is clear that we must have $ x^2 \equiv 1, y^2 \equiv 0$. This leads to solutions $ x \equiv 1, 7, 9, 15 \pmod{16}$, $y \equiv 0, 4, 8, 12 \pmod{16}  $. There are 16 solutions.
- Taking mod 125, since $n^2 \equiv 0, 1, 4 \pmod{5}$, if $5 \not \mid x, y$, then $x^2 - y^2 \geq 2$.

  - If $ 5 \mid x$, then show that there are 2 solutions to $y$.  This gives 50 solutions.
  - If $ 5 \mid y$, then show that 2 solutions to $x$. This gives us 50 solutions.
- Hence, there are $ 16 \times 100 = 1600$ solutions in total.

Comment: $2000=\color{red}{16}\times125$

Comment: You mean $x\equiv 1,7,9,1\color{red}5, y\equiv0,4\color{red}{,8,12}$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner (Sadly not initially.) I now do.